# defining a simple array of integers

Tags: c, arrays

Why can i do this?

```
int array[4]; // i assume this creates an array with 4 indexes

array[25]=1; // i have assigned an index larger than the int declaration

NSLog(@"result: %i", array[25]); // this prints "1" to the screen
```

Why does this work, if the index exceeds the declaration? what is the significance of the number in the declaration if it has no effect on what you can actually do with the array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting undefined behavior. It could print anything, it could crash, it could burst into singing (okay that isn't likely but you get the idea).

If it happens to write to a location that is mapped with the adequate permissions it will work. Until one day when it won't because of a different layout.

Answer (score 1):

it is undefined. some OS will give you segmentation fault, while some tolerate this. anyhow, exceeding the array's size should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

An array is really just a pointer to the start of a contiguous, allocated block of memory.

In this case, you have allocated 4 ints worth of memory.

So if you went array[2] it would think "the memory at array + sizeof(int) * 2"

Change the 2 to 25, and you're just looking at 25 int's worth of memory past the start. Since there's no checks to verify you're in bounds (either when assigning or printing) it works.

There's nothing to say somehting else might be allocated there though!

Answer (score 0):

The number in the decleration determines how many memory should be reserved, in that case `4 * sizeof(int)`.

If you write to memory out of the bounds, this is possible but not recommended. In C you can access any point in memory available to your program, but if you write to that if it's not reserved for that thing, you can cause memory corruption. Arrays are pointers (but not the other way around).

The behavior depends on the compiler, the platform and some randomness. **Don't do it.**

Answer (score 0):

It's doing very bad things. If the array is declared locally to a function, you're probably writing on stack locations above the current function's stack frame. If it is declared globally, you're probably writing on memory allocated to adjacent variables. Either way, it is "working" by pure luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your C compiler had padded your array for memory alignment purposes, and by luck your array overrun just happens to still be within the rounded-up allocation. Don't rely on it though.

Comment: Not at all likely (that would be *a lot* of padding!).  The only reason nothing 'bad' happened was because the code only reads the out-of-bounds memory.  Writing to it may corrupt other data or stack frames within the running program.  The value read is entirely non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

This is unsafe programming. It really should be avoided because it may not crash your program. Which is really the best thing you could hope for. It could give you garbage results. These are unpredictable and could really screw up your program. However since you don't know that is wrong because it not crashing it will ruin the integrity of your data. Since there is no try/catch with C you really should check inputs. Remember scanf returns an int.

Answer (score 0):

C by design does not perform array bounds checking.  It was designed as a systems level language, and the overhead of explicit run-time bounds checking could be prohibitive in a great many cases.  Consequently C will allow 'dangerous' code and must be used carefully. If you need something 'safer' then C# or Java may be more appropriate, but there is a definite performance hit.

Automated static analysis tools may help, and there are run-time bounds checking tools for use in development and debugging.

In C an array is a contiguous block of memory.  By accessing the array out-of-bounds, you are simply accessing memory beyond the end of the array.  What accessing such memory will do is non-deterministic, it may be junk, it may belong to an adjacent variable, or it may belong to the variables of the calling function or above.  It maybe a return address for the current function or a calling function.  In a memory protected OS such as Windows or Linux, if you access so far out of bounds as to be no longer within the address range assigned to the process, a fault exception will occur.